# Saying 'Today' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time, client-side, dayofweek

I'm making a simple plugin that shows shop opening hours. I've coded it and it looks quite good. It appears as a list similar to what I've typed below.

Monday - 9:00AM until 5:00PM
Tuesday - 9:00AM until 5:00PM
Wednesday - 9:00AM until 5:00PM

...and so on. The generated HTML looks like:

```
<div id="%id%container">
    <div id="%id%title">%text="Opening Hours"%</div>
    <ul class="%id%hours">
        <li>Monday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Tuesday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Wednesday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Thursday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Friday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Saturday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Sunday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Let's say today is Tuesday. Instead of reading 'Tuesday', I'd like it to just say 'Today' instead. Is there a way of accomplishing this with just Javascript (client-side)?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you show what code you used so that answerers can know how to change it?

Comment: Instead of putting it in a comment, could you edit it into your post (including line breaks?) It would also be a good idea to indent it by selecting the code and hitting command-K

Comment: [new Date().getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are, pure JS solution:

```
<div id="%id%container">
    <div id="%id%title">%text="Opening Hours"%</div>
    <ul class="%id%hours">
        <li>Monday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Tuesday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Wednesday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Thursday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Friday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Saturday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
        <li>Sunday<span>%text="9:00AM - 5:00PM"%</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
var dayNames = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thirsday","Friday","Saturday"];
var dayOfWeek = new Date().getDay();
var dayOfWeekText = dayNames[dayOfWeek]
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div[id="%id%container"] ul[class="%id%hours"] li');

window.onload = function(){
    for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++ ){
        if (elements[i].innerHTML.indexOf(dayOfWeekText) != -1){
            elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(dayOfWeekText),'Today');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/fNDSn/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to leverage the getDay() method in javascript to determine day of the week and then replace it programmatically.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp

EDIT: After seeing the source code, I think this would be easier if you added id attributes to your list items for reference. Then you could use some javascript like the following if your IDs were day0, day1, day2, etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var d = new Date();
  var obj = document.getElementById('day' + d.getDay);
  // TODO - replace day of the week on the 'obj' object
</script>
```

Not sure if you are planning to use a javascript framework like jQuery or not, but it would make it a little less verbose at the expense of including the source.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It should allow you to do exactly what you want.